# Standard library implmentation source that hasn't had names uglified

Tags: c++, std

Reading **C++** source code can obviously be a good way to learn and is just plain interesting when its a feature you know very little about. As far as standard library source goes this is difficult due to the **uglifying** of names.

Is the **uglifying** done through some sort of post-processing of the source code before it's inclusion in the standard library? If so, what happens to the original source code? Are there any repositories of non-uglified **C++ Standard Library** source code?

I'm interesting in looking at **C++11** and soon **C++14** features in particular.

I can't imagine maintaining code in this form would be very fun....

EDIT:

There's a proposal to do away with this process [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3400.html).

Comment: Are you talking about *name mangling*?

Comment: Can you give an example of this "uglification?"

Comment: Just so we know exactly what you're talking about, could you add a short example to your question?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He is not. He is talking about the fact that the standard library implementation details _have to_ use reserved identifiers (those start with `__` or `_<uppercase letter>`) in order to prevent name clashes with user macros.

Comment: @cdhowie: I think the OP is referring to the use of names like `_M_rep` and `__Ty` in standard libary code. Because the standard library is allowed to use those names :-)

Comment: Am I allowed to paste GPL'd source code on here?

Comment: I've also had instances where pasting or linking some standard library source in an answer of a question would have been nice, but given the OP being a novice, the uglifying of the names would have made it pointless.

Comment: well, with some simple search&replace, you could *beatify* the source..

Comment: @Troy: What you are talking is *style*, and what you call ugly others might call nice. At any rate, ugly or not, you can become familiar with the style in very little time, and the choice of names does not make the code *harder* to maintain (as long as the style is consistent and the names meaningful)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The uglifying of the names is encouraged (mandated?) by the standard to prevent name clashes. This has nothing to do with style. I understand it's need, but when reading code for learning purposes, it's a hindrance.

Comment: There's even a proposal to do away with it: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3400.html

Comment: Despite your "obviously" assumption, reading standard library code is *not* necessarily a good way to learn anything, because the standard library obeys different rules than any other code. It does not need to be portable (because it typically ships with, and assumes, a single specific compiler, and it is in some cases *required* to do non-portable hackery just so you don't have to. And, of course, all the names in the library code are not just ugly, but also reserved. You are not *allowed* to use similar names in your code. In short, I don't think there is much learning value in reading it

Comment: A tangentially related observation is that while *some* of the "uglification" is required (the std lib has to stick within the reserved names - those starting with underscores), everything else *could* be made readable. There is no requirement that the std lib use oddly named internal headers, or name template type parameters  unhelpful names like `_Ty` or other such tricks which just make the code less accessible.

Comment: @jalf: Not too sure about that. The standard cannot use any name that is not reserved for anything that is not documented. The issue here would be macros defined in user code *before* including the standard headers. Say that the template argument was `TYPE`, and that user code defined `TYPE`, then the standard headers would fail to compile. While you can claim that this is easy to fix (and it is) the fact is that different names in different implementations would make working code non-portable.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: you misunderstood me. I know that they have to stick within the reserved names (with underscores galore), but most implementations *also* typically pick needlessly short and cryptic names. `__allocator_type` is just as reserved as `_Alty`, but the former would be a wee bit more readable. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When learning from standard library implementations, please first of all note that the standard library has to obey certain harsh constraints which don't apply to code written by normal users. Also, some of the operations done by standard C++ libraries are somewhat esoteric and I would be worried if they were ever used by normal user's code (if you have a low-level library team in you company, they might do some similar stuff, though). In particular on constraint standard libraries need to obey is that none of the names used conflicts with any names used anywhere by users. Since users could define funny macros, the standard library needs to use names reserved for the standard library in user-visible contexts, e.g., the header files:

- names used in the standard C++ library for classes, functions, enumerations, etc. or tmeplates thereof (when applicable) are reserved.
- all names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter or names containing two consecutive undersscores are reserved in all contexts.
- there are a couple of other reserved names which are, however, typically not used in the headers because they are mostly not reserved in the context of macro names.

The things you specifically do **not** want to copy from the standard C++ library is the naming of the include guards: these typically start with one or two underscores and are all uppercase characters. Users are **not** allowed to use any of these identifiers unless they are specifically allowed to use them (e.g. you can use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` but you are **not** allowed to, e.g., write `_FOOBAR` anywhere in your program where it could be expanded by a macro (that is, I think you can write `"_FOOBAR"`).

To answer your actual question: all standard C++ library implementations I'm aware of (libstdc++, libc++, Dinkumware, RougeWave, and my own) are written using "uglified" names and there is no program converting them into this form. Basically, any program would have to deal with lots of exceptions which isn't quite feasible. I think, standard C++ library implementers just get used to the funny names. For my implementation I had made an effort to name everything with a common prefix so that the uglification could be undone using a simple `sed` script but I haven't followed that pattern everywhere.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a `sed` script for some of the other implementations. Do you maintain a commercial implementation or actually your own?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't maintained: [CXXRT](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) However, it is my own, although not everything in this code base is done by me (only the parts I was interested in, in particular locales and IOStreams).